# What's this anime with a scene with a large praying mantis?

Tags: inuyasha

I need to know what show this scene is from. In 2005, I was channel surfing and came across a show on [adult swim] and I got distracted by laughter and children playing. The animation was dated, so it had a Rurouni Kenshin style to it. There were two children, a boy and a girl playing in the forest at night. Then out of nowhere, this huge praying mantis appears and stabs the little girl from behind. I was in 4th grade at the time, so I was traumatized and quickly changed the channel. If you could help me figure out what this scene is from it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uhm... traumatized by that?

Answer (score 9):

Maybe [InuYasha](http://myanimelist.net/anime/249/InuYasha) at episode 28, there is a woman that transforms into a giant mantis.

[image: transform]

[image: transformed]

---

## [InuYasha](http://myanimelist.net/anime/249/InuYasha)

[image: cover]

## Synopsis

> Higurashi Kagome, after being pulled down a well by a demon, finds herself in Feudal Japan, where she learns that a powerful jewel has been reborn inside her body. After the jewel shatters in an attempt to retrieve it from one of the many demons who was after its power, Kagome must join forces with the half-demon Inu Yasha (also after the jewel's power) to track down the shards of the jewel before its power falls into the wrong hands.
>
> Source: ANN